# python: applying glob on the selected path

Tags: files, python, wildcards

Recently I have switched to python and now am focusing on the understanding how it could be applied to work with filles in the simular manner as I did it with bash:

```
# obtain path where we are mow
pwd = os.getcwd()
print("This is a directory with the script: %s" % pwd)
# join folder with the filles to be analysed to PWD
data = os.path.join(pwd,"data") 
print("This is a directory with the data %s" % data)
```

now how I could apply glob to load all of the filles inside the DATA with the extension DLG?
Something like this does not work

```
dirlist = glob.glob(data/"*.dlg")
```

Comment: what do you mean by load the files inside the DATA ?

Comment: in the folder data there are several filles with DLG extension. GLOB function is capable to load all of those filles preparing a new aray contained name of those filles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the **current working directory** to **data** and then execute **glob** :

```
#!/bin/python
import os
import glob
# obtain path where we are mow
pwd = os.getcwd()
print("This is a directory with the script: %s" % pwd)
# join folder with the filles to be analysed to PWD
data = os.path.join(pwd,"data") 
print("This is a directory with the data %s" % data)
os.chdir(data)
files_grabbed = [glob.glob('*.dlg')]
print files_grabbed
```